# nonetype can print but cannot be written into a txt file

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I run the following code in python and it does retire str-like result but when I want to write into my text file, it either wrote nothing or returns that it is a nonetype, so can not be written into a file. how should I convert the result back into str and write it into a file? thanks

```
f1 = open('Documents/new_corpus/raw-corpus/seg/word_seg/pos/pos_depression33.txt','w')
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
import hanlp
hanlp.pretrained.mtl.ALL
a = []
HanLP = hanlp.load(hanlp.pretrained.mtl.CLOSE_TOK_POS_NER_SRL_DEP_SDP_CON_ELECTRA_BASE_ZH)
with open('Documents/new_corpus/raw-corpus/seg/word_seg/seg2_depression1.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        HanLP([line],tasks = 'pos').pretty_print()
```